# How can I handle global variables that are common between two projects?

Tags: c, include, global-variables

I have two projects written in C: a client side and a server side, both of which contain lots of common global variables. I want to write a class (clientbot and serverbot using a interface Transaction) which will call the main function of each project.

I have moved all the common global variables in a header file and included it in both project. But on building it is throwing me linking error.

> Error 3   error LNK2005: "int g_nBytestoSend" (?g_nBytestoSend@@3HA) already defined in transimpl.obj agentBot.obj

Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: maybe you did not delete the original? or forgot #ifndef in the globals page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put the actual variables in the header, only `extern` declarations of those. Put the actual variables in a separate `.c` or `.cpp` file and link with that.

In the header (lets call it `globals.h`), you put this declaration:

```
extern int g_nBytesToSend;
```

Then you create a new code file to hold the actual variables (say `global.c`):

```
int g_nBytesToSend;
```

Let's imagine you had three code files `server.c`, `client.c` and `bot.c` and that you're using gcc. You would build this like:

```
gcc -o server.o -c server.c
gcc -o client.o -c client.c
gcc -o bot.o -c bot.c
gcc -o globals.o -c globals.c
gcc -o mybot server.o client.o bot.o globals.o
```

(Try to keep your number of globals small.)

Comment: I m using a open source project n both files have same global variables. i have to write a interface which call either of these two depending on situation

Comment: @honeybadger, how does it contradict with what Mat wrote?

Comment: @honeybadger, please clarify your question (edit the question itself), I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [protect](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/636372-use-ifndef-header-files) the header file with ifndef?

Comment: I m using a open source project n both files have common global variables. i have to write a interface which call either of these two depending on situation. So I have to keep this common global variable available to both files. Hence i used a header file

Comment: @honeybadger: you need to be clearer as to what is not working if neither my post (the I updated) nor Ilya Kogan's help you. Please edit your question with additional information (don't clarify you question in these comments).